# Randomly, my css does not load for my application

Tags: css, node.js

Why would my css file only load seemingly at random? How can I fix this issue? I'm using Nodejs without Express for reasons.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
console.log('request starting...');

    fs.readFile('./view.html', function(error, content) {
        if(error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end();
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

    fs.readFile('./css/appStylesheet.css', function(error, content) {
        if(error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end();
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at localhost on port 3000');
```

Just in case this portion is not where the problem is, the below code shows the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign In</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/css/appStylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "signIn">
            <p>Username</p>
                <input type = "text" id = "username" value = "" >
                    <script>
                    function username() {
                        var x = document.createElementById("username").value;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                    }
                </script>
        <p>Password</p>
            <input type = "text" id = "password" value = "">
            <p><button onclick = "password()">Submit</button></p>
                <script>
                    function password() {
                        var x = document.createElementById("password").value;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                    }
                </script>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, asynchronous is the key here.

In your code, there's just a single request processor, calling `fs.readFile` two times for two different files. Each calls have more-o-less similar callbacks for processing the content. The problem is, each of those callbacks *ends* the response with this line:

```
response.end(content, 'utf-8');
```

And now you have a classical race condition - if the second `readFile` wins the race (i.e., it finished the process of reading first), `CSS` file is served. If not, HTML file is served. Note that it doesn't matter whichever file was actually queried by the server, as your callback doesn't check the request at all!

What you (most probably) have to do instead is setting up the request listener so that it checks what has actually been requested by the client - and serve only this file. One possible (and very simple) approach:

```
function serveFile(filePath, fileType, response) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHead(500);
      response.end();
    }
    else {
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': fileType });
      response.end(content, 'utf-8'); 
    }
  });
}

var contentTypeFor = {
  '/view.html': 'text/html',
  '/css/appStylesheet.css': 'text/css'
};

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  if (request.url in contentTypeFor) {
    serveFile(request.url, contentTypeFor[request.url], response);
  }
  else {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

Check this (with `http://localhost:3000/view.html`), and you see that both requests are served correctly.